# JavaScript image cropping issue

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to select the image area which needs to be cropped.

```
function preview(img, selection) {
var scaleX = 100 / selection.width;
var scaleY = 100 / selection.height;

$('#thumbnail + > img').css({
width: Math.round(scaleX * 354) + 'px',
height: Math.round(scaleY * 448) + 'px',
marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
});
$('#x1').val(selection.x1);
$('#y1').val(selection.y1);
$('#x2').val(selection.x2);
$('#y2').val(selection.y2);
$('#w').val(selection.width);
$('#h').val(selection.height);
}


$(window).load(function () {
$('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ x1: 120, y1: 90, x2: 280, y2: 210, aspectRatio: '1:1', onSelectChange: preview });

});
```

This works fine but I'm using tabs to show different sections. When I click on the next tab I can see the image cropper which I don't want. How can I solve this?

Comment: I see you using a $ function, but that isn't standard JavaScript. If you are using Prototype, JQuery, Dojo, or some other JavaScript framework, you should mention that in the question. Also, try to put your code in a code block (see the buttons on top of the editor panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI,
I think you are using a div as the image cropper. If it is the case you can set the div attribute style.display='none' when you click on the other tab.